# Why does forms with single input field submit upon pressing enter key in input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Why is it that a `<form>` with a single `<input>` field will reload the form when the user enters a value and presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it does not if there are 2 or more fields in the `<form>`?.

I wrote a [simple page](http://testformenter.html?partid=123) to test this oddity.

If you enter a value in the second form and press Enter, you'll see it reloads the page passing the entered value as if you called `GET`. why? and how do I avoid it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>testFormEnter</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="partid2" id="partid2" />
  <input type="text" name="partdesc" id="partdesc"  />
</form>
  <p>2 field form works fine</p>
<form>
<input type="text" name="partid" id="partid"  />
</form>
<p>One field form reloads page when you press the Enter key why</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is a little known "Quirk" that has been out for a while.  I know some people have resolved it in various ways.

The easiest bypass in my opinion is to simply have a second input that isn't displayed to the user.  Granted not all that user friendly on the backend, it does work to resolve the issue.

I should note that the most common place that I hear of this issue is with IE specifically and not with FireFox or others.  Although it does seem to affect them as well.

Comment: Thanks, I wish it were documented somewhere. I wasted hours debugging a large page thinking it was something else, tied to my ajax. I only discovered the "quirk" after I extracted the code and started to delete line after line. 
What a waste of time!

Comment: And you are right, it's an easy fix with a hidden field. Incidentally if affects firefox 3.5.2. Maybe it's considered a feature.

Comment: Ah yes, I feel your pain....that is how I found out about it, say 5-6 years ago...

Comment: Also I discovered that a hidden field doesn't always work. On one page it did and another it didn't - also odd. but hiding the field with javascript did the trick.
You need to write an article "Things you don't know that will eat up your time" - thanks again

Comment: I am debugging in Chrome and the hidden field doesn't seem to work.

Comment: add a style that display is none, not type is hidden

Answer (score 50):

This is a [known bug in IE6/7/8](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=389736). It doesn't appear that you will get a fix for it.

The best workaround you can do for this, is to add another hidden field (if your engineering conscience permits). IE will no longer auto-submit a form when it finds that there are two input-type fields in the form.

**Update**

In case you were wondering why this is the case, this gem comes straight out of the [HTML 2.0 specification (Section 8.2)](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2):

> When there is only one single-line text input field in a form, the
>   user agent should accept Enter in that field as a request to submit
>   the form.

Comment: This also happens in Firefox 3.5

Comment: Spent hours debugging this in Chrome. Thanks for pointing out it came from spec.

Comment: The moment you, an entitled dev, are "by-design, RTFM"ed by w3org because you didn't read the document carefully.

Comment: If this was a bug, then only because IE stuck to implementing HTML 2 long past its sell-by-date. The section you found was already *long* out of date by the time you wrote your answer: HTML 2.0 came out in 1995, which was replaced by HTML 3.2 in 1997. This standard [**dropped dictating how browsers should handle form submission**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#form). HTML 4.0 (1999) merely talks about [activating a submit button](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3) in terms of *an example of submitting a form* (*e.g.* == for example).

Comment: Finally, HTML 5, published in 2012 (so 3 years after your answer), added the notion of [implicit form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#implicit-submission), codifying what browsers have been doing all along: submitting the form when a user hits enter in a single-line text field.

Comment: Adding hidden field does not work. The browser (chrome) still submits the form

Answer (score 9):

No, the default behaviour is that on enter, last input in the form is submitted. 
If you don't want to submit at all you could add:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Or in your input

```
<input ... onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
```

Of course there are more beautiful solutions but these are simpler without any library or framework.

Comment: I just ran into this issue for my websites. It seems to me that the latest chrome version now implements [W# SEC8.2](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2) which broke some functionality on sites I'm developing.

Answer (score 7):

Pressing Enter works differently depending on (a) how many fields there are and (b) how many submit buttons there are. It may do nothing, it may submit the form with no 'successful' submit button, or it may pretend the first submit button was clicked (even generating an onclick for it!) and submit with that button's value.

For example, if you add an `input type="submit"` to your two-field form, you'll notice it too submits.

This is an ancient browser quirk going back at least as far as early Netscape (maybe further), which is unlikely to be changed now.

> <form>

Invalid without an ‘action’. If you don't intend to submit anywhere, and you don't need radio button name grouping, you could just completely omit the form element.

Comment: thanks, good answer. Though I need the form to serialize the fields for Ajax. I could code it manually, but with many forms it would be a pain.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code that I used would use to solve the problem:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="partid" id="partid"  />
<input type="text" name="StackOverflow1370021" value="Fix IE bug" style="{display:none}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not reloading the page as such, it's submitting the form.

However, in this example because you have no action attribute on the form it submits to itself which gives the impression of reloading the page.

Also, I can't repro the behaviour you describe. If I am in any text input in a form and I press Enter it submits the form, no matter where in the form the input is located or how many inputs there are.

You might want to try this out some more in different browsers.

Comment: You're right I was not using the right words. It is submitting the form and since I don't specify an action it defaults to itself.

I copied the exact HTML and ran it in IE8 and Firefox 3.5.2.
An enter key in the first 2 fields, that are in the first form, do not submit the form, while an enter key in the third field does.

Answer (score 3):

as vineet already said, this is rooted in the html 2.0 specification:

here is how to prevent this from happening without screwing up your urls:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="partid" id="partid"  />
    <input type="text" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who answered. It's an eye opener that a form with a single field acts differently then a form with many fields.

Another way to deal with this automatic submit, is to code a submit function that returns false.

In my case I had a button with an onclick event, so I moved the function call with the added `return` keyword to the onsubmit event. If the function called returns false the submit won't happen.

```
<form onsubmit="return ajaxMagic()">
<input type="text" name="partid" id="partid"  />
<input type="submit" value="Find Part" />
</form

function ajaxMagic() {
  ...
  return (false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found for all of the browsers that I tested (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera) is that the first input `type=submit` element on the form has to be visible and has to be the first element in the form.  I was able to use CSS placement to move the submit button to the bottom of the page and it did not affect the results!

```
<form id="form" action="/">
<input type="submit" value="ensures-the-enter-key-submits-the-form"
                      style="width:1px;height:1px;position:fixed;bottom:1px;"/>
<div id="header" class="header"></div>
<div id="feedbackMessages" class="feedbackPanel"></div>
     ...... lots of other input tags, etc...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in both IE and Chrome.
It does not occur on Firefox.
A simple solution would be to add the following attribute to the form tag:
onsubmit="return false"

That is, of course, assuming that you submit the form using an XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, form with a single inputText field working as different in HTML 4.
onSubmit return false not working for me but the below fix bug is working fine

```
<!--Fix  IE6/7/8 and  HTML 4 bug -->
    <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="StackOverflow1370021" value="Fix IE bug" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by the following code but I am not sure if this a good approach.
By looking for input fields in a given form and if its 1 prevent the default action.

```
 if($j("form#your-form input[type='text']").length == 1) {
   $j(this).bind("keypress", function(event) {
     if(event.which == 13) {
       event.preventDefault();
     }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that's a feature, which I did also disable it though. It's not taking big effort to disable it. Just capture the enter key, ignore it, will do.