# Form not submitting when there is more than one input text

Tags: forms, input, submit, keypress, enter

This is a quite simple issue to describe. This was tested on Firefox (3.6), IE (8) and Chrome (8).

Here is the file doesnotsubmit.html

```
<form>
    <input />
    <input />
</form>
```

When the focus is on one of the input and you press enter, nothing happens.

Below is the file doessubmit.html

```
<form>
    <input />
</form>
```

When the focus is on the input and you press enter, the form is submitted.

Any insight on this inconsistent behavior ?

I know the form lacks a submit button, and thus is not semantically correct. Anyway, the submit process was meant to automatically be handled through jQuery dialogs buttonpane's buttons, and I wouldn't know how to place an additional <input type="submit" />.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say "not submitting" was desired behavior, but they added an exception to a form with one input for the sake of websites with search fields (which this is their typical pattern). Though I'm really on speculating here...

Comment: Well the insight is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021/enter-key-on-a-form-with-a-single-input-field-will-automatically-submit-with-get/1370314#1370314), see the link to the HTML Spec

Answer (score 1):

user754151 is correct. This is a known bug but i guess you can get rid of it just intercepting the enter keypress event.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solution for this issue.

1. The simplest solution is to add 1 more input field which will not visible to user.
2. you can bind the keydown event of that input field, and in that function just check keyCode == 13 then preventDefault().