# Changing what Enter button does on a simple form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021/enter-key-on-a-form-with-a-single-input-field-will-automatically-submit-with-get).

I really thought that `<input type="text" name="StackOverflow1370021" value="Fix IE bug" style="{display:none}" />` would fix this.

For clarity, I want the Enter button to do what the "Change" button does.
http://jsfiddle.net/RASgx/

Comment: In vanilla JS, or with a library?

Comment: Minor sidenote: You should clean up your HTML. There is for example neither a <input type="feild"/> nor a <input type="field"/>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your  tag to: `<form name="text" onSubmit="document.getElementById('change').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById('change').innerHTML)+parseInt((text.elements.field.value)); return false;">`

That will prevent the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `return false;` to make it **not** submit

> <form name="text" onSubmit="document.getElementById('change').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById('change').innerHTML)+parseInt((text.elements.field.value));**return false;**">

Updated version (3) of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RASgx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is highly not recommended, you can add in the onsubmit at the end:

```
return false;
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hkcBR/) is a fork of your code

Answer (score 0):

add `return false;` to your onSubmit handler to prevent the default.