# Hidden submit button wont submit in chrome when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, hidden, keypress

I have a problem with a hidden submit button. I have an input field I use for an Ajax(jQuery) chat, people should enter text and press enter to submit. This works fine in Firefox but not in chrome, I think it treats it as if it's not there.

I'm using the following code:

```
$('#CommentChatForm').submit(function(event){ 
    ...
}
```

And I use this to hide the submit button:

```
$('#CommentChatForm input:submit').hide();
```

Which makes the HTML look like this:

```
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

I've also tried using keypress() by adding the following on top:

```
$('#CommentMessage').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        $('#CommentChatForm').submit();
    }
})
```

This makes it work fine in Chrome but in Firefox it causes it to submit twice instead of once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the keypress handler you won't need the hidden submit button, so just remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, removed the button and added the keypress handler and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes you don't have control of HTML being generated by some widget or a module, so you style things with CSS.  This was the case with me too.  If found that in Chrome it works if you use

`visibility:hidden;`

but not if you use

`display:none;`

In FireFox it works either way. Hope this will be helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display it, then don't add it in html.

html:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="my_submit()">
<input type="text" id="msg" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function my_submit(){
    var msg = $('#msg').val();
    ....
    submit_on_my_own(msg);
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this way and without Submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#Username').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            $('#CheckLogin').submit();
            }
        }); 
    $('#Password').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            $('#CheckLogin').submit();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

works for me in chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/qEAeN/

might need to double check your js

Comment: For latecomers: This is because there is a single text input, which is part of the spec. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021.) [This example with 2 inputs](http://jsfiddle.net/qEAeN/98/) doesn't work.