# Form only submits when there is one input

Tags: html, forms

I have a `<form>` element surrounding several inputs:

```
<form>
  <div class="tr" id="widget306">
    <div class="td col-grab">

        <button type="button" class="button grab formwidget" id="widget611">m</button>

    </div>

    <div class="td col-name">

        <input type="text" name="name" value="target volume profile 1" id="widget607" class="formwidget textbox">

    </div>
    <!-- ... etc ... -->
  </div>
</form>
```

I would like to trigger a submit event on the form when the user presses enter while focused on an element (standard behavior for input elements wrapped in a `<form>` tag), but when I press enter, nothing happens ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/wPPXK/3/)).  If I remove all but one input element, the code works, and I get the expected behavior of pressing enter and triggering a form submit ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/wPPXK/4/)).

How do I get the desired behavior (pressing enter submits the form) in the first example where I have multiple forms?

Note: I have found this same behavior in Safari 5.1, Chrome 17, Firefox 9, and IE 9.

**Clarification:** I know I can just throw some Javascript at it, but I'd like solve it with just markup.

**Update:** as some of you have helpfully pointed out, I can get the desired behavior by adding an `<input type=submit>`.  The problem is I don't want the user to see the submit button.  I can't just set its `display` to `none`, because then browsers won't submit when return is pressed, so I borrowed from QUnit and set the following:

HTML:

```
<input type=submit class=hide-me />
```

CSS:

```
.hide-me {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
  top: -10000px;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any buttons that look like `<input type="submit">` anywhere.

Comment: good point, for some reason, even though i don't want a submit button, i need it in order for the press-enter-to-submit functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed that forms don't like to submit without a submit button. The problem is simply resolved by adding a submit button.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YPUmE/) for a demonstration.  Furthermore, browsers submit when a user presses enter by default, so fix that and you won't need a javascript trigger to cause it.

**EDIT:**
If you don't want to use a `<input type="submit">` simply because it's styling deficiencies, consider a `<button type="submit">`, it should also do the trick.  If you just don't want a submit button at all, stick with the CSS hack.

Answer (score 1):

After trying it myself I couldn't believe it either.

Looks like this is the issue:

[Why does forms with single input field submit upon pressing enter key in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021/enter-key-on-a-form-with-a-single-input-field-will-automatically-submit-with-ge)

Answer (score 0):

It's default behaviour for browsers to automatically submit simple forms (like search ones) which is why it's working when there is only one input. I believe if you want this functionality on complex forms you will need to use javascript. If you're not against using jQuery the following should do the trick.

```
$(function(){ 
     $("#formid input").keypress(function(event){
         if (event.which = 13){
             $("#formid").submit();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an element 
    `<input type="submit" name="xx" value="submit" />`
   it will trigger submit behavior automatically.
2. you can also use jQuery to handle press event.

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. i use this on my textarea with tinymce for a chat system

```
<script>
function getKeystroke(e)
{
  var keynum;


  keynum = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;



  switch(keynum)
  {
     case 13:  /* enter key */
        document.getElementById("s_say").click();
        document.getElementById("s_message").focus();

        break;
  }

}
</script>
```

s_say is the ID of the input type submit btn.

Comment: It would be easy to do with Javascript, but I want to do it with just the markup.

Comment: i see what you want is to submit the form without input type like submit.