# Google App Script - Enter key in input textbox - how to catch or disable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an html page published as a web app through Google app scripts.  On the page is an input box (textbox) the user types a number to search for.  If they click the 'search' button beside the box, it works fine.  If they type the number and then press 'enter' on the keyboard, it throws a 400 error ('The requested URL was not found on this server. ').

input area code:

```
<input type="text" id="claimSearchBox" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" />
<input type="button" id="btnsearchClaims" class="btn-md btn-success" onclick="getOrders" value="Search for a Claim"  />
```

javascript:
(this works for the button)

```
document.getElementById("btnsearchClaims").addEventListener("click", getOrders);
```

(this does not work for the input box)

```
document.getElementById("claimSearchBox").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('event:  ' + event.keyCode);
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
  console.log('correct key');
  getOrders();
}
});
```

I also tried this, which shows what keys are pressed, but as soon as I press enter, it goes to the 400 error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("claimSearchBox").keyup(function(e){
  console.log(e.keycode);
    console.log("worked");

  });
});
```

Any suggestions?  Is there a way to disable the 'enter' if I can't redirect it to the getOrders()?

**Edited to add...if I don't have any programming for the input box and the user presses enter - it goes to the error (page is blank - error is shown in console).

***Found the problem:  Turns out it was an issue of this input box being the only input box on the form. When the user hits enter, it automatically submits the form! I found the issue/solution here: [Why does forms with single input field submit upon pressing enter key in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021/why-does-forms-with-single-input-field-submit-upon-pressing-enter-key-in-input)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you get further with your code.

I see that you are invoking jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Can you confirm that the page you are displaying is properly loading jQuery?

Your html should have something like this present.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you use your debugger and successfully enter your readythen you have jQuery loaded.

With jQuery, you could simplify your event handling.

Replace

```
document.getElementById("btnsearchClaims").addEventListener("click", getOrders);
```

With

```
$("#btnsearchClaims").on("click", getOrders);
```

Replace

```
document.getElementById("claimSearchBox").addEventListener("keyup", 
function(event) {
```

With

```
$("#claimSearchBox").on("keyup", function(event)...
```

Comment: Thanks @terrywb.  I do have jQuery loaded correctly.  Turns out it was an issue of this input box being the only input box on the form.  When the user hits enter, it automatically submits the form!  I found the issue/solution here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021/why-does-forms-with-single-input-field-submit-upon-pressing-enter-key-in-input)