# Antd Form doesn't submit when there are more than one text input inside

Tags: forms, reactjs, google-chrome, antd

I have a simple example where for some reason form stops calling `onSubmit` callback if I add more than one text inputs and push 'Enter' key while one of the inputs is focused.

Here is a link on CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KePXOj?&editors=001.

This one works:

```
<Form onSubmit={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); console.log(e)}}>
    <Input/>
</Form>
```

And this doesn't:

```
<Form onSubmit={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); console.log(e)}}>
    <Input/>
    <Input/>
</Form>
```

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Does it work when you manually press ok?

Comment: Yes, it does work when I click ok.

Comment: Does not work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/5zm7wj7nq4

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an antd issue, it is a known quirk that forms with only a single input fire onsubmit when pressing enter while if they have multiple inputs they do not.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021/why-does-forms-with-single-input-field-submit-upon-pressing-enter-key-in-input) might be related

Comment: really? I feel like it's common to hit onSubmit for a login for with email/password.